# Amending URL for "list_display_links" in Django 1.6 admin change list

Tags: python, django, django-admin

What I'd like to know is how do I change the URL that's applied to the items listed in `list_display_links` of an `admin.ModelAdmin` class?

More specifically I would like `/admin/contacts/contacts/12345/` to become `/contacts/12345/`.

All solutions I could find were quite old, somewhat convoluted and geared towards doing something else on top - so I was hoping there's some obvious way I'm missing.

(I was kind of expecting `list_display_link_url` (or similar) to exist to over-ride in the `ModelAdmin`...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Override standard `ChangeList` (in your `admin.py`):

   ```
   from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList

   class ContactChangeList(ChangeList):  
       def url_for_result(self, result):  
           pk = getattr(result, self.pk_attname)  
           # YOU PROBABLY WANT TO CHANGE NEXT LINES!
           return reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (self.opts.app_label, self.opts.model_name),
                          args=(quote(pk),),  
                          current_app=self.model_admin.admin_site.name)
   ```
2. Tell Django admin to use your new `ContactsChangeList` instead of standard one:

   ```
   class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  
       ...  
       def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):  
           return ContactChangeList
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If following the suggestion of Alex Yakovlev, you might revert to the original implementation of ChangeList, which in older versions of Django (1.2 by sure) was:

```
def url_for_result(self, result):
    return "%s/" % quote(getattr(result, self.pk_attname))
```